# Ruby on rails: Rspec routing error when testing for a successful http status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, url-routing, rspec-rails, rails-routing

So I am having trouble passing these specs in a ruby on rails application:

```
require 'rails/all'

RSpec.describe WikisController, type: :controller do 
let(:user) { User.create!(email: "user@email.com", password: "password") }
let(:wiki) { Wiki.create!(title: "New Wiki Title", body: "New Wiki Body", private: false, user: user) }


   describe "GET show" do
     it "returns http success" do
       get :show
       expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
     end
   end

   describe "GET edit" do
     it "returns http success" do
       get :edit
       expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
     end
   end
end
```

when I run these specs, i get these errors:

```
Failures:

  1) WikisController GET show returns http success
     Failure/Error: get :show

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"wikis"}
     # ./spec/controllers/wikis_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) WikisController GET edit returns http success
     Failure/Error: get :edit

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"wikis"}
     # ./spec/controllers/wikis_controller_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

the reason i am confused is because they work fine in the browser. Also, when i run rake routes, i get this:

```
                    root GET    /                              wikis#index
                   wikis GET    /wikis(.:format)               wikis#index
                         POST   /wikis(.:format)               wikis#create
                new_wiki GET    /wikis/new(.:format)           wikis#new
               edit_wiki GET    /wikis/:id/edit(.:format)      wikis#edit
                    wiki GET    /wikis/:id(.:format)           wikis#show
                         PATCH  /wikis/:id(.:format)           wikis#update
                         PUT    /wikis/:id(.:format)           wikis#update
                         DELETE /wikis/:id(.:format)           wikis#destroy
```

So, these errors don't make sense to me because clearly i do have those routes with those controllers. Can someone provide me some insight as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rspec includes `show, edit` actions which require `id` as your results from `rake routes`.

Try `get :show, id: 1`

Comment: Thank you. Still new to rails and rspec, the answer seems so obvious now that you said it